# Use execCommand to remove an element so it is undoable

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

So I am trying to add a delete button that appears on `hover` of elements inside a `contenteditable`, and clicking the delete button removes the element. Right now, I have something like this:

```
button.on("click", function() {
  item.remove();
  button.hide(); 
}
```

However, I would like to make the removal undoable, so the user could press `command+z` to `undo` the deletion. As far as I know, you would have to use `execCommand` to delete the element, in order to do this (A custom solution for undoing is not an option). Is there any way to somehow use `execCommand` to delete a specific node (even something unselectable, like an `iframe`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `delete` command. You can set the selection to encompass the element in question, call the command and it will be undoable, at least in the following simple example, which works in all the browsers I tried:

```js
function deleteElement(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById("toBeDeleted");
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNode(el);
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  document.execCommand("delete", false, null);
}
```

```html
  <input type="button" onmousedown="deleteElement('toBeDeleted'); return false" value="Delete">
  <div contenteditable="true">Use the button above to delete <b id="toBeDeleted">this bold text</b></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Comment: I'll add that this doesn't work if the trigger you want to use comes from an `onkeydown`...only from an `onkeypressed`.  But some keys like ESC don't trigger onkeypressed.  So if your clearing action is tied to ESC *(e.g. clearing current input)*, and you'd like that to be undoable *(for someone who didn't mean to do that)*, you'll have to implement that manually with your own undo queue.  Which is inconvenient, but it's all worth it because I can sleep a bit safer at night knowing that escape can't add to the undo queue...in a page that otherwise had free reign over all content.  :-/